# Como percorrer linhas de um SELECT em uma STORED PROCEDURE no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Sem ser com a utilização de `CURSOR` e `WHILE` no `SQL Server`, que outras formas seriam possível percorrer as linhas de resultado de um `SELECT` em uma `STORED PROCEDURE`?

Comment: de mais informações sobre oque pretende fazer? as duas melhores formas de percorrer os registros são while e cursor, cada um deve ser usado em uma situação..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tirando `CURSOR` e `WHILE` não acredito que exista outra forma.

No Oracle temos um [`FOR` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1536), mas isso não existe no SQL Server. Porém não vejo a real necessidade de ter ainda mais formas de iterar um `SELECT` além desses dois casos.

Iterar os resultados, mesmo que usando um `CURSOR`, já não acho uma boa ideia pois não é performático, imagine um `WHILE` ou outro loop qualquer.